# Passing tracking variables with PHP echo?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website that I'm sending traffic to but then geo-redirecting with the Maxmind javascript code.

When the user first arrives at the page there are tracking variables appended to the url... &c1=, &c2=, &c3=, etc...

Can someone help me grab the tracking info from the url and then php echo it in the redirect? Not sure exactly how this is done and I would appreciate the help. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"
type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">

var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country  == "US")   
{
<!--
window.location = "http://example.com/redirect/usa/index.htm?&c1=PHP ECHO HERE&c2=AND HERE
//-->
}

else   
{
<!--
location.href
//-->
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close, just need to open php

```
window.location = "http://example.com/redirect/usa/index.htm?&c1=<?php echo $_GET['c1']; ?>&c2=<?php echo $_GET['c2'];?>
```

You can also you the short hand for php echo `<?= ?>`

to get the variable from the url use the super global `$_GET` so one of the variable might be `$_GET['c1']` check the [manual for more information](http://www.php.net//manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Hey, I understand that part. What I need to know is how do I grab the variable from the referring url and then echo it. So $someVariable; would be the c1= value from the referring url.

Answer (score 0):

If it's param in URL you can see :

[$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

[parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) can also be useful